# How to reset form after ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x = > x.LanguageId,
    new SelectList(Model.Languages, "LanguageId", "Name"),
    "--- select ---",
    new {
        id = "ddlLanguage", 
        @class = "profile-setting-dropdown"
    })
```

I want, after ajax submit, to reset form with this dropdown.
Is it possible to reset whole form?
If not how to select `option item` from [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) as option item doesn't have `value`?

Comment: Since this happens 100% client-side, your C# code is not relevant to this question. You should be showing your HTML output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using JavaScript: `document.formname.reset()`.

Comment: I thought it was `document.forms["formname"]`? Not having a go, just never seen that before :)

Comment: They'll both work. You can address the form directly or through the forms collection.

Comment: Cool, never knew that. Every days a school day!